# WPF Move image with arrow keys

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Hello i am trying to make a snake game, but instead of using a shape i want to use an image for the head and some other image for the rest of the body.
I am new to WPF and all the tutorials i found only use shapes.
What i want to be able to do at this point is move my image by using the arrow keys and eventually after i get that working  detect collision with other images on the board.
This is my mainwindow xaml code. It consists of a simple image(DogeIcon) that i want to move as explained above and another image(cat) that is an obstacle.

```
<Window x:Class="DogeSNake.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DogeSNake"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Image Name="DogeIcon" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="64" Margin="33,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="64" Source="media/doge.png" MouseEnter="RectangleMouseEnter" />
    <Image Name="CatIcon" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="445,247,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" Source="media/cat.png" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is not a grid but a canvas...

```
<Window x:Class="DogeSNake.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DogeSNake"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=MyCanvas}">
    <Canvas Name="MyCanvas" KeyDown="Canvas_KeyDown" Focusable="True" >
            <Image Name="DogeIcon" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="64" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="64" Source="media/doge.png" MouseEnter="RectangleMouseEnter"/>
            <Image Name="CatIcon"  Canvas.Left="200" Canvas.Top="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" Source="media/cat.png"/>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

In the code bahind...

```
    private void Canvas_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Down)
        {
            Canvas.SetTop(DogeIcon, Canvas.GetTop(DogeIcon) + 10);
        }
        else if (e.Key == Key.Up)
        {
            Canvas.SetTop(DogeIcon, Canvas.GetTop(DogeIcon) - 10);
        }
        else if (e.Key == Key.Left)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(DogeIcon, Canvas.GetLeft(DogeIcon) - 10);
        }
        else if (e.Key == Key.Right)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(DogeIcon, Canvas.GetLeft(DogeIcon) + 10);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Considering that it should become a "snake game", it might as well operate on a Grid, and change column and row indexes on key input. The important point is that you define an appropriate number of columns and rows, and don't set Margins on the Images.